# SIngle instance of application, Data refresh in One Window

Tags: qt

I have an application in Qt. It is a window. This window has certain data that is displayed.

This window is launched from another application.

It is quite possible that the application be launched from different instances of the other application, with different data.

Let's say I already have one instance of the application running, how do I ensure that if the application is called again, it should not launch another instance, and should instead refresh the data in the already existing window with the new set?

In a nutshell, One application having a single window, which displays refreshed data passed along with a different call.

EDIT : I checked it out. It should be sufficient to solve my problem. However, I cannot find the relevant files in my Qt installation. I learnt it was never a part of Qt solutions and has to be downloaded manually. If this is the case, will it affect any licensing issues?

**EDIT 2 :** 
I have an Instance, let's say, A, of the application open already. I try and launch an instance B. B sends a message to A. 
Is it possible to check for certain conditions to be satisfied by A, using this message, and then the decision of whether to open B or not?

As such...

1. A is already running
2. B is now launched
3. B sends a message to A
4. A tries to confirm something using this message
5. if message is true( let's say), keep A running and open B as a new instance
6. if not...close B, and let A use this new information to refresh data

Is this possible using QtSingleApplication, especially step 6 ? Or will a new instance close as soon as it detects an already running instance?

Also, how do I integrate QtSingleApplication within my application? Do I only need to include the header and cpp? I don't wish to build a dll and work like that. Is there any other configuration required?

I'd be obliged if anyone could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is [QtSingleApplication](http://doc.qt.digia.com/solutions/4/qtsingleapplication/qtsingleapplication.html). When you call the application a second time, you can check `QtSingleApplication::isRunning()` to see if another instance already exists. If it does, simply use `QtSingleApplication::sendMessage()` to alert the first instance that something has been called. Simply set up your application to be able to receive those messages (which you can be made aware of by connecting to the `QtSingleApplication::messageReceived()` signal), and react accordingly when you receive that signal.

Comment: I checked it out. It should be sufficient to solve my problem. However, I cannot find the relevant files in my Qt installation. I learnt it was never a part of Qt solutions and has to be downloaded manually. If this is the case, will it affect any licensing issues?

Comment: Classes that start with "Qt" are not part of the lib only "Q" classes come with qt - Qt classes are add ons designed by the devs

Comment: @user1173240 : The sources are hosted at Gitorious. `git clone git://gitorious.org/qt-solutions/qt-solutions.git` to download the sources. As for licensing, QtSolutions is LGPL like Qt. Unless you have a commercial license for Qt because you can't use LGPL, you will be fine.

Comment: ""void QtSingleApplication::messageReceived ( const QString & message )   [signal]

This signal is emitted when the current instance receives a message from another instance of this application.""

Which is the current instance? i.e. Who receives this signal? The instance which called the SendMessage ( new instance ) or the instance which is already running ( old instance ). In case of the latter, how do I pass on a message to the new instance as to what it should do?

Comment: The second instance calls `sendMessage()`, and the already running instance receives the `messageReceived()` signal. Encode whatever message you wish to transmit in the QString argument of `sendMessage()`, and that is what the first instance will receive with `messageReceived()`.

Comment: Thanks. That helps clear some stuff. If I have a situation, where there are 2 instances of the application already running, and a third starts, sendMessage() will broadcast the message to all instances present? Or only to any of the one.

Comment: Only the first one to have been launched will be considered as the single running instance. Therefore, if the 3rd one calls `sendMessage()`, only the first instance will receive it.

Comment: Oh..so the second one won't receive such a communication? How does it identify which was the instance first launched?

Comment: http://doc.qt.digia.com/solutions/4/qtsingleapplication/qtsingleapplication.html#isRunning : `QtSingleApplication::isRunning()` returns `true` if another instance is running (meaning the caller is the second instance), or `false` if the caller is the only (first) instance running.

Comment: Aah, alright. I get it. Just one final clarification. Is there any way to pass on a message back to the new instance from the old? The already running instance needs to inform the new whether it is to keep running or not. Is there a way to do that? Can the already running instance call 'sendmessage()' to inform the newly launched instance of something..?

Comment: Unfortunately no. With QtSingleApplication, communication is one-way. You will need to implement your own way of having the first instance communicate with the other ones for that.

Comment: @Fred Alright. Thank you for your help. You've been very helpful.